# Не работает cmd в Windows 11

Tags: windows, консоль, cmd, ос

При запуске cmd выводится данная ошибки:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3007]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

[процесс завершил работу с кодом 1 (0x00000001)]
Теперь вы можете закрыть этот терминал с помощью клавиш CTRL+D. Или нажмите клавишу ВВОД для перезапуска.
```

Что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Как запускаете?

Comment: через windows terminal похоже

Comment: Да, через windows terminal.  И через cmd.exe тоже не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновите windows Terminal до 1.18 если более старый.

в файле C:\Users\eri\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json

```
    "profiles": 
    {
        "defaults": {},
        "list": 
        [
....
            {
                "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "\u041a\u043e\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0434\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u043a\u0430"
            },
```

Профиль командной строки должен выглядеть так.

или закрой все окна терминала и грохни папку LocalState

Comment: Версия самая последняя. Профиль выглядит примерно так же. Но все равно не работает.

Comment: примерно? какие отличия?

Comment: Значение guild другое и name "Windows PowerShell"

Comment: А все я починил. Помог последний способ. Спасибо

Comment: Windows PowerShell это другая консоль.